# Make GPG Agent Permanently Store Passphrase

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

I recently got GPG setup on my Mac:

```
brew install gpg;
brew install gpg-agent;
```

And generated a key pair with a passphrase.

I added `use-agent` to my `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` and `allow-preset-passphrase` to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

I successfully decrypted a file using:

```
gpg --use-agent --output example.txt --decrypt example.gpg
```

which prompted me to enter my private key passphrase. The trouble is, when decrypting subsequent files, `gpg-agent` again prompts me for this passphrase.

Currently, my passphrase is a really long string which is near impossible to type each time. I would like `gpg` to behave like `ssh-agent` wherein the passphrase is stored securely and remembered forever (even between sessions).

I understand that this might decrease security if my laptop was comprised, but this inconvenience would probably deter me from using `gpg` all together.

I'm not sure if:

```
default-cache-ttl 31536000
max-cache-ttl 31536000
```

are the options I'm looking for to store between reboots There's sadly no `man` entry for `gpg-agent`.

How can I make `gpg`/`gpg-agent` remember my private key passphrase forever?

Comment: The value for those options is in seconds, the default being 600. And, yes, they are the droids you are looking for...

Comment: I think you want `max-cache-ttl` insteal of `...-tcl`, and then only for GnuPG 2.1 and later, before that use `maximum-cache-ttl`

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the environment variable `$GPG_AGENT_INFO` set.

What you can do as a temporary measure is run `gpg-agent bash` (or the shell of your choice) and retry decryption.

On the long run this might just be solved by first logging out and then log back in to your system, then check echo `$GPG_AGENT_INFO` again. If it is there chances are good that you no longer have to retype your passphrase every time.

Most Linux distributions have hooks for this in place and I expect OSX to be as user friendly, the requirement, of course being that `gpg/gpg-agent` is available (installed) before starting your session.

Comment: OSX is user friendly. I installed GnuPG from gpgtools.org and it saves my passphrases to the Apple Keychain if desired.

Answer (score 0):

You should start the agent like this.

```
eval $(gpg-agent --daemon --write-env-file "${HOME}/.gnupg/.gpg-agent-info)"
```

Then in your `.bashrc` file add the lines:

```
if [ -f "${HOME}/.gnupg/.gpg-agent-info" ]; then
    . "${HOME}/.gnupg/.gpg-agent-info"
    export GPG_AGENT_INFO
fi
```

Comment: WARNING: "--write-env-file" is an obsolete option - it has no effect